# err_ssl_pinned_key_not_in_cert_chain

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-pinning, key

I have a question: how I can prevent this error from server side? We have a new cert, and it's valid, but users getting this error.

Earlier, I've added HTTP response header Public Key Pins with 1 valid key, but I've deleted it from IIS.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have to wait until the time period you set in `max-age` is passed.

In this situation it's better to roll back to the old certificate, add a new pin to `Public-Key-Pins` header and wait for some time until the vast majority of clients receive the updated header.

In future, just don't rely on only one pin - always have a reserved certificate.

Comment: Thanks, but if remove this header, those browsers, that have cache broken version, still will have this error?